# python %s string substitution and "self"?

Tags: python, repr, string-substitution

see this code in pyyaml doc, why `"Dice(%s,%s)" % self` works ? there are two `%s` but only one var `self`?

```
>>> class Dice(tuple):
...     def __new__(cls, a, b):
...         return tuple.__new__(cls, [a, b])
...     def __repr__(self):
...         return "Dice(%s,%s)" % self

>>> print Dice(3,6)
Dice(3,6)
```

http://pyyaml.org/wiki/PyYAMLDocumentation#Constructorsrepresentersresolvers

Comment: Because `self` is a `tuple` containing two items.

Comment: ah ... right. Thanks!

Comment: ekhumoro - sounds like you should make this an answer instead of a comment - and be credited for it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Dice` is a derived class from `tuple`, and it is a `tuple` of length 2.

You can see for example that

```
>>> print yaml.dump(Dice(3,6))

!!python/object/new:__main__.Dice
- !!python/tuple [3, 6]
```

So in your context, it works well, it is indeed a tuple of length 2 and so can resolve the string used.